# Is there any online .plist editor?

Tags: iphone, editor, plist

I'm interested in an online application like the tool that comes with XCode, that shows the keys and values as rows, in an editable manner and handles xml plists (I don't care if it handles binary ones as well).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So, I was wondering the exact same thing, and when I saw this question and its answer, I said "Screw it, I'm making one!" And so I did. Two days later, here's my answer to you:

http://tustin2121.github.io/jsPlistor/

jsPListor (version 1 as of Aug 8th, 2013) will allow you to paste in the contents of an xml plist into it (via the Import button) and edit it with drag and drop and the like. When you're done, hit Export and it will package it all up into a valid plist for you to copy and paste back into the file.

There's still some bugs and glaring vacancies (like the Data Editing Dialog), but it functions. Future versions will attempt to allow saving via html5 download, and loading of files into data rows.

Feel free to examine, contribute, and submit bugs at the github repo: https://github.com/tustin2121/jsPlistor

Comment: @EladKarako There is no reason why it should have stopped working suddenly. Also, it works fine for me and I am on Chrome.

Comment: that's cool that it works for you :]] - I've later found out that I should strip everything but the first root (as in- no headers no doctype etc...)

Comment: Doesn't work with binary PLIST files.

Comment: https://www.anyplist.com is way better.

Answer (score 1):

I have resigned myself to the fact that there probably isn't one I will ever find.  What I have found, however, is that JSON format and text PList format are very similar, and there are plenty of JSON editors available online and for windows and mac both.  It may not be suitable for your needs, but it suited my needs just fine.  By using nothing more than a couple of find & replaces in Notepad you can get 90% of the way to a plist file.  The only big issue is semicolons vs. commas.

If you're working on a small enough file, that could be done manually.  With larger files, a simple utility app to convert JSON to PList files would probably be pretty simple to whip up if you've got the urge.

Again, this all applies only to text formatted plist files.  Most plist editors on mac at least can save a plist in text format.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Plistinator](https://plistinator.com/) - its a native C++/Qt app for Mac, Windows and Linux desktop.  So not an online tool, but it is at least portable and runs cross-platform (in case that is what the request for a web-based editor was about).

I'm not sure if the JS version handles binary files (Plistinator does).  If you have a Mac you could edit them via the JS editor if you convert binary to XML via

```
plutil -convert xml myfile.plist
```

Note that will over-write myfile.plist with the XML version, which may not represent all the same information that the binary version can.

Full-disclosure: I am the author of Plistinator and the $12.99 goes to pay for my ramen & rent.

Comment: Costs $19.99 now.  It may be more worth your time to download Apple's developer tools and use the plist tools from that package.

Comment: The link on this is broken now, FYI

Comment: Link is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any plist editors online, at least not as functional as Plist Editor with Xcode.

You could use an online XML-editor, like [Xmlia2.0](http://xmlia.com/), and code it yourself.

Why would you ever want an online tool for editing XML-files when you've got Plist Editor from xcode?

Comment: So I could tweak plists even when I'm not on a mac.

Comment: Unfortunately none of those results have the same functionality as the XCode PList Editor

Comment: Yeah, the Xcode Plist Editor is a great tool, I agree.
I don't think any other Plist Editor has *all* of the functins that XcodePlistEditor has got.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one once back in the day (for the old non-XML plist files). The structure is very regular, so it's not hard to create something that looks and acts more or less like the XCode plist editor.

I don't know off-hand of any online XML editors, but they must exist. Given a DTD-savvy XML editor, you ought to be able to edit plist files pretty easily.

Answer (score -4):

Any web app that accepts `.txt` documents will edit plists just fine. Likewise for `.xml`

Comment: "like the tool that comes with XCode, that shows the keys and values as rows"

He doesn't want to deal with raw XML.

Comment: Yeah, well he might not have a choice, so it's a good idea to suggest alternatives now isn't it?