# Represent "less-than" symbol in Sublime Text regex in syntax definition

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm working with an ancient pre-XML markup that uses codes of the form "$=x", where x may be an alphabetic character or a symbol on the keyboard, such as `;` (semicolon), `?` (question mark), or `<` (<strike>right</strike> left angle bracket, aka <strike>greater-than</strike> less-than). [Note after editing: the confusion manifested in the question as originally phrased goes to the heart of the problem. See my comment to the accepted answer. RS]

So I've modified a copy of XML.tmLanguage syntax definition file in my User folder to identify the eleven different categories that these codes represent, so I can easily see them in the large text files (which also contain XML markup) I'm working with.

For all the symbols except `<` I'm able to escape the symbol by preceding it with a backslash. But in the Boost regex engine that ST2 uses, `\<` is how you indicate that you want to match only at the start of a word. Consequently I've been unable to get this code to be properly recognized and highlighted.

I've looked everywhere for how to escape the `<` symbol in this circumstance. I've tried preceding it with 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 back-slashes; and I also tried using the hexadecimal escape code `\x{3009}`. [Note: this is the code for greater-than instead of less-than.]

All in vain. (A few alternatives didn't generate an error message but also didn't highlight the code.)

Because the codes I'm working with need to be colored differently, I can't use a generic symbol in lieu of `<`, and I can't specify it either. How do I get this?

Comment: You don't need to escape the symbol `<` in a regex.

Comment: That's true. But in the syntax definition if I add `\$=<` the full string doesn't end up highlighted in my file. (Whereas, by contrast, `\$=>` works fine.)

Comment: did you try `\$=[<]` ?

Comment: Yes, alas, it does not work, resulting as before in the message of a "premature end of char-class in regex."

Comment: `\$=[<]` gets truncated at the `<`, becoming `\$=[`. (Though strictly the whole file should be rejected, according to XML rules.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tmLanguage file is written in XML, so Sublime Text feeds it through an XML parser first, before giving pieces to its regex engine's parser.

XML uses `<` to open tags such as `<string>`, so you can't use it directly as a character. Instead, there are these standard character references:

- `&amp;` for `&` (ampersand)
- `&lt;` for `<` (less than)
- `&gt;` for `>` (greater than; not required)
- `&quot;` for `"` (quote mark; only required in attribute values quoted with `"`)
- `&apos;` for `'` (apostrophe; only required in attribute values quoted with `'`)

So **use `<string>\$=&lt;</string>` in the syntax file.** When Sublime Text reads the file, its own XML parser will turn this into `\$=<` for the regex parser.

Backslash sequences don't help because the XML parser passes them through unchanged to the regex parser, which then sees `\<` or `\\`, neither of which are what you want.

`\x{3008}` is passed by the XML parser to the regex parser, where it's decoded to `〈`, a character which looks somewhat similar to `<` but doesn't match it. `\x3C` would work though.

By the way, tmLanguage files use plist (property list) XML, so you can convert it to a format that's easier to edit, or use a plist editor such as http://tustin2121.github.io/jsPlistor/ (from [Is there any online .plist editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492497/is-there-any-online-plist-editor)).

Comment: I had tried the entity for greater-than and that didn't color the `$=<` code in my text. Your answer made me realize the reason it hadn't worked was I had used the wrong entity — I needed to enter `&lt;` and not `&gt;` (this confusion is in my question — I showed `<` but called it the right angle bracket when it's actually the **left** angle bracket). So my regex had two entries for `>` and none for `<`, which is why it didn't show up right. (I suppose if I'd used entities for both of them I would have been confusing them but gotten the right results.) Thanks for pointing what I couldn't see!

Comment: Aha, glad to have helped! Those can be some of the hardest bugs to find. Apart from the less-than/greater-than mixup though, I think your question is generally useful for highlighting another blind spot: the need to quote/escape/encode at the right level when you have layered notations. Do you want to edit your question to say "less than"?

Comment: Good idea. I have edited the question while still trying to indicate that I thought my problem was about escaping, but it was in fact based on my confusion of less-than and greater-than for the symbols `<` and `>`.

Comment: Btw, still can't figure out why \x3C doesn't work. By all logic it should.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `&gt;` for a syntax file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: `&gt;` and `&lt;` are used in Sublime syntax files as greater than and less than.  Why would you try and delete my answer?

Comment: The issue is not with the content but the form: it's phrased as a question, of the sort that belongs in the comments. "Use `&lt;`." would be a better way to word it.

Comment: @AGS Yeah, I blame the computers: we're battling software here, and computers can out-pedant us any day :-)

Comment: See my comment to deltab's answer. In essence, your answer is correct — except that it's `&lt;` that I needed to use. I confused the two entities in my question, which is why `&gt;` didn't appear to work. –